# Storing access_token - javascript

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, xss, access-token, refresh-token

I need to store access/refresh tokens at browser.
I read that It is not safe to store AT and RT in localStorage nor sessionStorage. 
If I store AT and RT in localStorage and I will implement security steps to prevent XSS attacks. Would it be safe to store it in there?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can store your tokens in the local storage, as long as you sanitize client-side data before giving back the page to the client.

Example: client asks for the page `/user/?name=<script>[malicious script which wants to steal stored tokens]</script>`. Server should escape the `<` and `>` characters before giving the page back to the client (for instance, substituting `<` with `&lt` and `>` with `&gt`). So the script will not be executed once the client has received the page.

Check this article for a deep explanation: https://www.checkmarx.com/2017/10/09/3-ways-prevent-xss/

Comment: Note that this is a very naive answer with regard to both token storage and xss. This question has been answered many times before, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56296134/where-should-a-spa-keep-a-oauth-2-0-access-token/56297242#56297242).